# Computing the distribution from which this algorithm samples from

Tags: ds.algorithms, pr.probability

Assume we have a set of integers $X_0=\{x_1\ge x_2\ge\ldots\ge x_n\}$.

Let $r\in(0,1]$ be a parameter and consider the ranking process:

- i=0
- while ($X_i\ne\emptyset$)

  - let $M = \max \{x\in X_i\}$   (i.e., the maximum of the numbers in $X_i$).
  - Let $C = \{x\in X_i | x \ge r\cdot M\}$ (the set of numbers which are at least $r\cdot M$)
  - Pick a uniform random number $y\in C$ as the $i$'th ranked number.
  - Set $X_{i+1} = X_i \setminus \{y\}$ and increment $i$.

The goal is to compute the rank distribution $D$ of $x_i$ (the input is the set $X$ and an index $i$).

> **How fast can we find $D(X_0,i)$?** (also - is there a fast way to approximate it?).

Currently I'm using a simple Monte Carlo simulation, which is quite slow for my application.

---

For example, consider $X_0 = \{5,4,3,2,1\}$ and let $r=\frac{1}{2}$.

The distribution of $x_3 = 3$ is as follows:

- With probability $\frac{1}{3}$ it is ranked first.
- With probability $\frac{5}{18}$ is ranks second (notice that if $5$ is ranked first, then the chance $x_3$ is ranked second is only $1/3$, but if $4$ was ranked first, it has a probability of $1/2$).
- With probability $\frac{7}{36}$ is ranks third and with the same probability it ranks fourth.

The output is then $D(X_0,3) = <1/3, 5/18, 7/36, 7/36, 0>$.